# Convert SQL Server Query to MS Access to Update Table

Tags: sql, ms-access

Could anyone help with this.  I don't use Access often, but this process I'm building needs to utilize Access for the business to use.  I have the following code, which will not work in Access.  I keep getting the error 'Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression'.  Would anyone be able to convert this query into something Access will accept.

```
UPDATE Auto_DailyDiary_PrimaryTbl a
SET a.TotalDiary = sub.TotalDiary
FROM 
(
SELECT CaseEEID, Count(CaseID) as TotalDiary 
FROM dbo_Case 
WHERE CaseStatus <> 6 
GROUP BY CaseEEID
) sub
WHERE sub.EEID = a.EEID AND a.DiaryDt = Date()
```

Comment: Have you tried fully qualifying the where clause, instead of aliases? Access' t-sql does not like aliasing for expressions.

Comment: Yes, I've tried with and without aliases.  Still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure Access doesn't like having a joined group by subquery in an update query.

Maybe try something like this?

```
UPDATE Auto_DailyDiary_PrimaryTbl
SET TotalDiary =
    DCOUNT('CaseID', 'dbo_Case',
        "CaseStatus <> 6 AND " &
        "CaseEEID = '" & Auto_DailyDiary_PrimaryTbl.EEID & "'")
WHERE DiaryDt = Date()
```

Comment: Now I'm geting the error 'Operation must use an updateable query'

Comment: updated it to use DCount. It looks like your query is simple enough that it won't create a performance problem. Otherwise I think you'd need to use a temp table for this.

Comment: Both EEID and CaseEEID are strings.  Will that make a difference with your query?

Comment: updated it to treat the EEIDs as strings. Hopefully they don't have any apostrophes in them.

Comment: You are awesome.  That's exactly what I've been spending hours on today trying to obtain.  Thank you very much.